# ¿Cómo conseguir los datos de un json?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

He estado tratando de obtener unos datos de un json que recibo del servicio Web mediante una Ajax, me trae la respuesta y la puedo ver en la consola con todos los datos.

Aquí la petición con Ajax.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.kupomcity.com/gamma/api_v2.php?_opt=categorias_act=view"
  }).then(function(data) {
    nombres = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Aqué la respuesta por consola.

> [{"id":"16","name":"cafeteria"},{"id":"5","name":"Calzado"},{"id":"25","name":"Cancha
>   de Futbol"},{"id":"8","name":"Casa de
>   Thom"},{"id":"4","name":"Comida"},{"id":"24","name":"Comida
>   Mexicana"},{"id":"7","name":"Comida
>   Rapida"},{"id":"13","name":"Entretencion"},{"id":"21","name":"Entretenimiento","sub":{"id":"5","name":"Cancha
>   de
>   Futbol"}},{"id":"23","name":"Gastronomia","sub":{"id":"16","name":"Comida
>   Mexicana"}},{"id":"10","name":"hola"},{"id":"26","name":"Hotel costa
>   rica
>   jaco"},{"id":"6","name":"Hoteleria","sub":{"id":"16","name":"Hotel
>   costa rica
>   jaco"}},{"id":"20","name":"Mascotas"},{"id":"3","name":"Moda
>   Mujer"},{"id":"22","name":"Paracaidismo"},{"id":"12","name":"shell"},{"id":"19","name":"Shopping","sub":{"id":"16","name":"Mascotas"}},{"id":"11","name":"sushi"},{"id":"17","name":"Tatuajes"},{"id":"1","name":"TEST","sub":{"id":"16","name":"TEST
>   2"}},{"id":"15","name":"TEST 2"},{"id":"2","name":"TEST
>   2"},{"id":"9","name":"TEST
>   PRODUCCION"},{"id":"18","name":"zapatillas"}]

Lo siguiente es que quiero solo obtener los nombres, los cuales estan bajo el nombre `"name"` como se puede ver, necesito solo nos nombres para poder cargarlos con `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenés casi todo hecho.

Solo te falta acceder a los datos desde nombres dentro de la función que está en `then()`.

Por ejemplo `nombres[0].name` tiene el valor "cafeteria".

0 es la posición dentro del array de objetos json.

Solo un comentario: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` es como hacer `x + 1 - 1`. jQuery ya te esta devolviendo el dato como json.

Answer (score 2):

Tan solo necesitas acceder las propiedades del objeto por medio de la notación de punto (.):

```
nombres[x].name
```

Para iterar en el objeto puedes utilizar forEach (ES5+)

```
nombres.forEach(function(datos) {
    console.log(datos.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.kupomcity.com/gamma/api_v2.php?_opt=categorias_act=view"
  }).then(function(data) {
    $.each(data,function(indice,fila){
        var nombre = fila['name'];
        var id = fila['id'];
    });
});
```

como podrás ver en los datos fila le pongo como parámetro la key del JSON, asi obtengo el valor recibido.